# python3 - psycopg2 - execute sql file

Tags: sql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, execute

i have this basic sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE `app_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and want to execute it via python:

```
connect_str = "dbname='dbname' user='user' host='192.168.1.101' password='password'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(connect_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()

fd = open('file.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()
sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')
for command in sqlCommands:
    print(command)
    if command.strip() != '':
        cursor.execute(command)
```

When i execute this via "python3 app.py", it connects, but i just get:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE `app_users` (
```

But i have no idea why.. anybody could help me with this issue?

thanks and greetings

Comment: I suggest to look into the type of quote you are using. This ` is different to this ' and each programming language will have different ways to interpret them, parsing and escaping.

Comment: i usually use \ to escape the quoted character to executing sql in python. Something like this  CREATE TABLE \'app_users\' ( ...

Comment: i replaced ` with ' and \' . Both result in the examt same error..

Comment: i removed them all, results in: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "(" ... any help?

Comment: Forget about my previous comment. It seems that your question should be "How to convert this MySQL `create table` script to the PostgreSQL"

Comment: yap, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper Postgresql syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE app_users (
    id serial,
    email varchar(200),
    password varchar(200),
    primary key (id)
)
```